# Can't install nvidia drivers on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, graphics, 22.04

I'm using a VM with Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to do GPU pass-through.

Nvidia graphic card is being detected on my VM

```
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I did install the recommended nvidia drivers given by

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Which is nvidia-drivers-390

However, when I run nvidia-smi it gives me

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

Further exploring the root cause I actually found

```
               NVRM: API mismatch: the client has version 530.30.02, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has version 390.157.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
```

However, my graphic card only supports up to nvidia-drivers-470 since it's a GT 740M graphic card.
How can I remove the client API 530 version since it is not on the list of drivers installed?

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64            install
libnvidia-common-390                install
libnvidia-compute-390:amd64         install
libnvidia-compute-418-server:amd64      deinstall
libnvidia-decode-390:amd64          install
libnvidia-encode-390:amd64          install
libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64            install
libnvidia-gl-390:amd64              install
libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64            install
nvidia-compute-utils-390            install
nvidia-dkms-390                 install
nvidia-driver-390               install
nvidia-kernel-common-390            install
nvidia-kernel-source-390            install
nvidia-prime                    install
nvidia-settings                 install
nvidia-utils-390                install
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390           install
```

**UPDATE:**

I did find some folders using the following command

```
sudo find /usr/lib -iname "*nvidia*530*"
```

I removed and then followed the answer of @Saxtheowl and now there are Nvidia-520 files. Some witch craft for sure :/

Comment: It might be a version mismatch

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remove completely the existing Nvidia Drivers and reinstall a proper version

first purge the Nvidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia.*'
sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo rm -rf /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/nvidia*
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia*
```

then add the proper directories

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

then install the good drivers `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470` then disable the nouveau drivers

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'blacklist nouveau' > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo 'options nouveau modeset=0' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf"
```

then update the initial ramdisk `sudo update-initramfs -u`

then reboot

if there is still error check `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings` to be sure that all Component are upgraded correctly

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps, however, it seems to not work, despite having a slightly different output 


```
               NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 520.61.05, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 470.161.03.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Comment: I am not sure if I have answered your question, you could try also by repeating the step and sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver to get sure to have the latest version

Comment: Problem is that my nvidia graphic card is a legacy one (GT 740M) which I can only use max 470 nvidia driver

Comment: I updated my answers, follow the step, I think I might not be able to help you if that does not fix your problem